# MVC Web API Attribute Routing: Route Constraints Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I am using the Attribute Routing for Web API nuget package.

My `RegisterRoutes(HttpCollection routes)` method looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(HttpRouteCollection routes) 
{
    routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(config =>
    {
        config.AddRoutesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        config.AutoGenerateRouteNames = true;
        config.InMemory = true;
        config.PreserveCaseForUrlParameters = true;

        // Define type constraints for parameters on GETs
        config.AddDefaultRouteConstraint("id", new IntRouteConstraint());
        config.AddDefaultRouteConstraint("studentId", new IntRouteConstraint());
        config.AddDefaultRouteConstraint("campusId", new IntRouteConstraint());
    });
}
```

Here is one of my controllers (comments removed for brevity):

```
[AttributeRouting.RoutePrefix("SchoolInfo/Campus")]
public class CampusController : ApiControllerBase
{
[ResponseType(typeof(CampusApiEntity))]
[GET("{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        // Do stuff here - not important for the question
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that I can access the above method like this:
`http://localhost:55697/schoolinfo/campus?id=2`

but when I try to do this:
`http://localhost:55697/schoolinfo/campus/2`

I get the following error:

> The constraint entry 'id' on the route with route template
>   'SchoolInfo/Campus/{id}' must have a string value or be of a type
>   which implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint
>   entry 'id' on the route with route template 'SchoolInfo/Campus/{id}'
>   must have a string value or be of a type which implements
>   'IHttpRouteConstraint'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The constraint entry 'id' on the route
>   with route template 'SchoolInfo/Campus/{id}' must have a string value
>   or be of a type which implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint'.]
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Object constraint, String parameterName,
>   HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
>   +293    System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection
>   routeDirection) +99
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot,
>   HttpRequestMessage request) +195
>   AttributeRouting.Web.Http.Framework.HttpAttributeRoute.GetRouteData(String
>   virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request) +131
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +107
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +233
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase
>   context) +60
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +82
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

I'm not sure how to go about solving this because I already have a constraint specified for the id parameter. When I googled the error, the only results I found involve setting config settings that I already have above.

I checked my routes.axd file and I do have this in there:

```
GET, HEAD, OPTIONS  SchoolInfo/Campus/{id}  controller: Campus, action: Get, id: IntRouteConstraint, namespaces: [MyAssemblyName].Controllers.SchoolInfo, defaultSubdomain: www, routeName: Campus_Get_1
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**

If I change my GET attribute from `[GET("{id}")]` to `[GET("{id:int}")]`, it works. So the issue seems to be with the default route constraints. The problem is I was really hoping to use those because I have id all over the place and it seems redundant to constantly be specifying its type when it's always an int.

Another thing I noticed is that the `IntRouteConstraint` class is found in 4 different assemblies:

```
AttributeRouting.Web.Constraints
AttributeRouting.Web.Http.Constraints
System.Web.Http.Routing.Constraints
System.Web.Mvc.Routing.Constraints
```

However, the `AddDefaultRouteConstraint()` method takes an `IRouteConstraint` as its second parameter, and only the `IntRouteConstraint` in `AttributeRouting.Web.Constraints` implements that interface, so that is the assembly I included. I'm not sure if that is the correct one or not. Maybe that is somehow related to the issue?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Web API has in built attribute routing support..have you considered using it?

Comment: Thank you!! I think I thought I had to use the library, and it must have caused a conflict with the built in functionality. I got it working after uninstalling the library.